# Groovy null is less than zero?

Tags: groovy, boolean-logic

I found that in groovy

`(null<0) == true`

I have not found documentation on this kind of operation and I don't know is a valid result or there is something wrong.

Anyone can tell me more?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not only is null less than zero, it's less than everything:

```
assert null < Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

All comparison operators are null-safe in groovy, and null is always less than any non-null value.  There's some documentation on the comparison operators here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in the documentation page don't specify how null is evaluated in a boolean operation. In the page is writen only 'Note that all the following comparison operators handle nulls gracefully avoiding the throwing of java.lang.NullPointerException'.